# "Until" followed by past perfect or past simple

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

Recently we have been learning tense sequence with using after, before and so on. One of them - ***until*** turned out troublesome for me.

My first exercise was to write this sentence with ***until***:
*not to agreed to take Kevin + they see how well we get on.*

Logic says to me that *not to let* was the first action and *seeing* was the second action.

> They **hadn't agreed to** take Kevin until they **saw** how well we get on.

My teacher told me English sometimes wasn't mathematical and logical and this sentence should sound like that:

> They **didn't agree** to take Kevin until they **had seen** how well we get on.

I said to myself: " Ok. After *until* it should be past perfect (simple or continuous)"

The second exercise:
*She didn't watch television. They bagan to broadcast signed TV programmes.* *(use until)*

I wrote this sentence accoring to my rule *After **until** we use past perfect!*

> She **didn't watch** television until they **had begun** to broadcast signed TV programmes.

According to my teacher this was wrong and this sounds better:

> She **hadn't watched** television until they **began** to broadcast signed TV programmes.

It is the first time I have been shocked so much by English.
Who knows and has time to explain?

Comment: "They will not let me take Kevin until they see how well we get on." *Until* regulates sequence; tense is temporal, as always. Consequently it's fine to apply *until* to future events, and restricting it to past tenses/formations is wrong.

Comment: @Łukasz: *Let* is an unfortunate verb choice for your context, since the past and present tense forms are identical. Maybe you'd be better comparing, say, *"They hadn't **agreed** until they saw it"* with *"They didn't **agree** until they saw it"*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it, but I asked to explain "until"

Comment: Neither of your answers was wrong. True, English is not always mathematical and logical, but it is surprisingly flexible. We could debate the subtle nuances of meaning between your versions and hers. But if she wants you to do it her way, she had better come with a reasonable explanation of why her versions are "better"!

Comment: In your first example (where the subject of both phrases is the same [they]), I’d omit the second “they” and say “...until seeing ... .”

Answer (score 2):

Trying to tap into your teacher's mind:

It seems that your teacher wants you to decide how the events in the sentence are arranged chronologically and to use past perfect for the event that happened further in the past or before the other one. Let's check this hypothesis!

- Example 1:

*not to agreed to take Kevin + they see how well we get on*

They want to see how well we get on **before** they agree to take Kevin. So we have:

**First** they see how well we get on -> previous event -> past perfect (had seen)

**Second/after that** they (may or may not) agree to take Kevin ->later event -> past simple (didn't agree)

The result:

> They **didn't agree** to take Kevin until they **had seen** how well we get on.

- Example 2:

*She didn't watch television. They bagan to broadcast signed TV programmes.*

**At first** She didn't watch television. -> previous event/circumstances -> past perfect (hadn't watched)
**Later** They began to broadcast signed TV programmes. -> later event -> past simple (began to broadcast)

The result:

> She **hadn't watched** television until they **began** to broadcast signed TV programmes.

It works!!!

I agree with the comments that: many variations (including the ones where both clauses are in the same, e.g. past simple, tense) are correct; *until* doesn't have to be restricted to past events (and you can even preserve the logic followed in this post - as in Andrew Leach's example: *They will not let me take Kevin until they see how well we get on.*).

Answer (score 1):

***Until*** as a ***subordinating conjunction*** (to connect an action or an event to a future point in time)

*I will not agree to take Kevin until I have seen how well we get on*

*I do not agree to take Kevin until I see how well we get on*

***Until*** as a ***preposition*** (meaning *up to (the time that)*)

*I will agree to take Kevin until his Mum arrives*

*I didn't agree to take Kevin until I saw how well we got on*

*She hadn't watched television until they began to broadcast signed TV programmes*

source: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/until

Comment: Just a note, but it is also correct to say: She didn't watch television until they began to broadcast signed TV programmes.  FYI:  In America we write "programs."  "Programmes" is the British way.

Comment: All of these are examples of *until* being used as a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this other example similar to the one you mentioned above.

Example:

"The accused man refused to speak until he had spoken to the judge."
I think the use of the Past Perfect here is not that of expressing a fact of the past but a non-factual event.
It's like when we say:

"He wishes he had spoken to the judge".

or

"He'd rather the judge had spoken to him".

Comment: Yes: does _until he had spoken to the judge_ modify 'refused' or 'speak'?